# Maintaining session with web server

Tags: c#, wcf, session, cookies, https

I have a WCF service that is consuming a website. Before anyone points out the obvious flaw and inherent instability in this approach, please forgive me, i have been forced to work on this.

The flow of the transaction is as follows :

Channel -> WCF Service ->(HTTP POST/GET) -> Website

Steps :
PostStrOnUrlRandom is called in a loop, passing it the string to be posted(strPost), the url(url) and CookieJar(CookieJarR) containig cookies from previous post.

1. HTTP GET on the url(not in below code)
2. I get the HTML page in response, parse it using XPATH, confirm it is correct page and save Cookies
3. POST strPost passed on this method on the url.
4. Get response HTML page, parse it using XPATH
5. Fetch next url and strPost from DB
6. Post the next strPost on the next url

I have to do this for 5 urls. Then i have to send response back to the Channel. The Channel then sends me another request, and i have to do another POST. I do this by using the same cookies I used for previous requests.

**This is where the problem arises, I get back an Internal Server Error 500. If i do retires on this POST, using the same strPost, url and Cookies it works after 3-4 retires. I cannot understand why this is.**

Code is as follows :

```
public HttpWebPostResponse PostStrOnUrlRandom(string url, string strPost, string Refer, CookieCollection cookieJarR)
    {

        log.Debug("Method Entery [PostStrOnUrl]");
        StreamWriter myWriter = null;
        string resultHtml = null;
        HttpWebResponse objResponse = null;
        HttpWebPostResponse hpr = null;

        HttpWebRequest objRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        objRequest.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
        objRequest.Timeout = 90000;
        objRequest.CookieContainer = cookieJar;
        objRequest.Method = "POST";
        objRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        objRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        objRequest.MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 100;
        objRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:46.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/46.0";
        objRequest.Referer = Refer;
        objRequest.Host = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Host"];
        objRequest.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8";
        objRequest.Headers.Add("Origin", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Origin"]);
        objRequest.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");
        objRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
        objRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
        objRequest.KeepAlive = true;

        log.Debug("Making HttpWebRequest to" + url);

        Uri target = new Uri(url);
        log.Debug("Target Url : " + url.ToString());
        foreach (Cookie cookie in cookieJarR)
        {
            objRequest.CookieContainer.Add(cookie);
            cookieJar.Add(cookie);
            log.Debug(cookie.Name + "" + cookie.Value + "" + "" + cookie.Domain);

        }

        try
        {
            myWriter = new StreamWriter(objRequest.GetRequestStream());
            myWriter.Write(strPost);
            log.Debug("Posting on Url StrPost =" + strPost);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            log.Debug(e.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            myWriter.Close();
        }

        log.Debug("Making Request.");

        try
        {
            objResponse = (HttpWebResponse)objRequest.GetResponse();
            using (StreamReader sr =
                new StreamReader(objResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                resultHtml = sr.ReadToEnd();
                sr.Close();
            }
            hpr = new HttpWebPostResponse(objResponse.ResponseUri.ToString(), resultHtml, objResponse.StatusCode.ToString());
            return hpr;
        }


        catch (Exception e)
        {
            log.Error(e.Message);
            log.Error("Exception", e.InnerException);
            return null;
        }
    }
```